# Loop script when completed

Tags: loops, powershell

What can I add to make this start over from the beginning after it completes?

```
mode con: cols=35 lines=5
$tag1 = ""
while (-not ($tag1)) {
  $tag1 = Read-Host 'Enter tag # or Q to quit'
}

    mode con: cols=80 lines=46

    cls

    sc.exe \\$tag1 start RemoteRegistry;

    cls

    start-sleep -seconds 2

    cls

    $OSInfo = get-wmiobject -class win32_operatingsystem -computername $tag1;
    $OSInfo | Format-Table -Property @{Name="OS Name";Expression={$_.Caption}} -AutoSize;
    $OSInfo | Format-Table -Property @{Name="System Boot Time";Expression={$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.LastBootUpTime)}} -AutoSize;
    $OSInfo | Format-Table -Property @{Name="OS Install Date";Expression={$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.InstallDate)}} -AutoSize;

    "`n"

    "Current Date & Time: $(Get-Date -Format G)";

    "`n"

    Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem -Computer $tag1 | Format-Table -Property @{Name="Username";Expression={$_.username}} -Autosize;

    Get-EventLog system -computername $tag1 -InstanceId 2147489657 -Newest 10 | format-table EventID,TimeWritten,MachineName -AutoSize;
```

Comment: Not sure how, that is why I am asking.

Comment: do you want it to just continue to start over for ever?

Comment: Well the script asks for a computer system name. I enter that and it tells me computer info, but once it tells me the info, it closes quick. I want it to ask for another $tag1 once it completes. So I dont have to open it again and again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might have to check the syntax on "$tag != 'Q'"  but basically this should continue to ask you for tags until Q is entered.

```
mode con: cols=35 lines=5 
while ($tag -ne "Q"){
$tag1 = ""
while (-not ($tag1)) {
$tag1 = Read-Host 'Enter tag # or Q to quit'
}
if($tag1 -eq "Q"){break}
mode con: cols=80 lines=46

cls

sc.exe \\$tag1 start RemoteRegistry;

cls

start-sleep -seconds 2

cls

$OSInfo = get-wmiobject -class win32_operatingsystem -computername $tag1;
$OSInfo | Format-Table -Property @{Name="OS Name";Expression={$_.Caption}} -AutoSize;
$OSInfo | Format-Table -Property @{Name="System Boot Time";Expression={$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.LastBootUpTime)}} -AutoSize;
$OSInfo | Format-Table -Property @{Name="OS Install Date";Expression={$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.InstallDate)}} -AutoSize;

"`n"

"Current Date & Time: $(Get-Date -Format G)";

"`n"

Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem -Computer $tag1 | Format-Table -Property @{Name="Username";Expression={$_.username}} -Autosize;

Get-EventLog system -computername $tag1 -InstanceId 2147489657 -Newest 10 | format-table EventID,TimeWritten,MachineName -AutoSize;
}
```

Comment: It keeps looping the same variable rather than asking for a new one and typing q or Q to quit doesn't work.

Comment: there try now, move $tag = "" inside the first while

Comment: Yeah that works good. Only thing is that q and Q to quit don't work. hmm.

Comment: try that, sorry ive never actually used powershell, i added a check if tag is Q just break out of the script

Comment: Was thinking about adding that to it. Seems to have cleared up any issues. Thanks. You never used it before but know the commands? What is it similar to that you can compare?

Comment: well while loops and if statements are basic programming flow controls.  They are present in almost every language.  I just googled powershell string comparison, and powershell if statement for correct syntax.